# Requesting police report and criminal applications

Tags: traffic

I am in Massachusetts and I got a criminal traffic citation. How can I request police report and criminal citations?

Comment: How long ago was this ticket made.  As the defendent in this case, the government must turn over all relevent documentation.  A call to records would likely suffice.

Comment: Three weeks ago.

Comment: Criminal? As in not just a ticket, but misdemeanor charge?

Comment: True. Some charge.

Comment: "A call to records." Would you be a bit of specific?

Answer (score 1):

The citation itself is on file in the court where you'll have charges. Obtaining it should be as easy as walking in to the clerk's office and asking for it.

The incident report may be different. In some courts, it will just be filed with the citation, which should make it easy to get. And in some places, police will just give you a copy if you ask for it, though I'm not sure what Massachusetts' laws are on that. If you can't get it either of those ways, you may be able to access it in the discovery phase of your case. Especially if it gets that far, you should definitely get an attorney to help you out.